# How do i speed up save, deploy , test in salesforce production?

Tags: force.com

When i change any data into salesforce code using eclipse and trying to save that then eclipse takes too much time but when i am doing this thing in sandbox it will get saved , deployed and synchronized quickly .

Is there any way to decrease the delay between saving , deploying and synchronizing the code to server using eclipse or any other tool?

[image]

Comment: Most likely not, the reason its taking so long is that **all** tests in production are being executed when you push in any code. This is not the case in a sandbox, where no tests get executed.

Comment: BarCotter - you should post this as an answer, as its spot on.

Answer (score 12):

Its not possible to speed up the deploy to a production instance. The reason its taking so long is that all tests in production are being executed when you push in any code. This is not the case in a sandbox, where no tests get executed.

If you are using two separate orgs (dev and sandbox) for development, which it seems you are based on your diagram. Then production should not be the org where you combine both codebases. Untested code should **NEVER** be deployed into a production environment. You should consider syncing up your dev org and sandbox so that they have the same copy of all code or introduce a new sandbox as shown below

[image: Updated overview]

Comment: Is there any way to stop the test cases while saving the code onto server using eclipse or any other tool ?

Comment: No, its not possible to save to a production org without all tests being run. This is to insure that there is at least 75% test coverage and that all tests pass. It also makes sure that your code hasn't broken any other code (either your code or 3rd party code) in the production org.

Comment: Currently i am changing the external css and pages code to redesign the application. So i need to test it again and again after saving and it is taking too much time to save a single comma or space or bunch of code.

Comment: You should be doing all that testing in a sandbox rather than a production org.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other technique by which i can make changes and can see effected changes ?

Comment: Right now i am testing into the sandbox but problem is to integrate all thing to production in minimum time.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Normal process would be either develop in a sandbox or developer org. Once you are happy with the code you can move it to a sandbox (if you're using a dev org) and then test your code there. Once your happy that the new code is working correctly and hasn't broken any of your other code, you can move it to production.

Comment: Ok I ll explain you the full scenario ---

Comment: Actually we are using Sandbox , Dev and production enviornments and i am working on designing and testing the html , css and visual force pages in sandbox with old code . the problem is one of my teammate working on dev in which he has done all his stuff related to functionality and this functionality code(dev) is being uploaded to production enviornment and i have redesigned the application in sandbox. with old code. now i need to update this redesigned application into production.

Comment: Then you should be using a second sandbox to do this other development in.  Never develop in production.  There is no reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only changing client-side resources for VF development, remember, you can reference those from anywhere. You shouldn't be inlining your JS or CSS anyway, so while you're fine-tuning, why not stick them in your own content server, edit them there, and then the refresh is immediate.

I've done this two ways.

One is to run a local static web server and reference it in my VF pages via localhost. This obviously only works if you are writing and testing on the same machine as the server. There was a [good blog article](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/05/instantly-reloading-visualforce-static-resources.html) on this in the developerforce blogs not too long ago.

The other is to serve static content from a public web server. I've typically done this with a heroku instance. There is a small lag while you push to your heroku repo, but nothing like waiting for your test code to run.

**BUT**

The reason we force you to run tests is so you don't screw up your production system! As has been said, all development should be done in a sandbox or developer edition org then pushed to production after thorough testing. So I would still suggest these techniques, but in reality you should be doing them in a system that is ring-fenced from your production org.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for small things such as CSS or javascript is to upload those files as static resources within salesforce. These are just files you upload to static resource records. Please take a look at the [document here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm)

[Example Reference / Usage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are also some third party tools that can help specific steps in this process. For example, it's a best practice to check the code of the production environment before you deploy to make sure there have not been any critical changes to the code in the production environment that could have an impact on your code.

OwnBackup.com takes meta data snapshots over time so you can compare the code before you started the project and right before you deploy to make sure that it's sfae to deploy.

Additionally getting test data and refreshing the sandbox can slow down the entire process both during and between sprints/development cycles. They recently deployed a new tool that let's you replicate environments and the sync the full sandbox on your own schedule. This a lone can save a day or two of developer time.

Comment: Who is "they" that "recently deployed a new tool that lets you replicate environments and sync the full sandbox on your own schedule"? What's the name of the tool? Please provide details and links to support your post. You can use the edit button at lower left to update it. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Hurrey !!!! I got the solution to this problem.

You can save the pages , components , css  etc through salesforce enviornment.

Here are the Steps -->

1. Go to login.salesforce.com
2. Type your creadentials and logged into the SF.

3.Click on the name top corner , right hand side and click setup option.

4.click develop , here all the static resources, components etc are listed .

1. just click on any static resources, components click edit button there on the upper side.

e.g.

```
Develop --> Pages --> xyz.page --> edit -->(after changes)--> quick save --> save (finally)
```

it will not take too much time.

*Note : For Apex Classes you need to change into Sandbox or Dev org after testing you can deploy onto server through eclipse and it will take time.*

Comment: You can't directly edit most code directly in production.  And even if you can, like with VF, you should still test in a sandbox and deploy to sanity check your work.

Comment: It is not possible to edit Apex classes in a production environment. The edit button is not there. You shouldn't be trying to do so in the first place. Develop in a sandbox and deploy to production.