# Can anything be done to accelerate Ant deployment times?

Tags: deployment, ant, quick-deploy

We are using Ant (a mix of command line, as well as through Atlassian Bamboo/AWS) to do sandbox-to-sandbox deployments. To narrow the focus of this question, let's assume unit tests are not being run.

We have compiled all classes/triggers through the web UI. **Is there anything else that can be done at the org level to speed up these deployments?** They do not take an unreasonable amount of time, but any time gained makes a small extra step worthwhile.

I've seen [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/deployment-with-force-com-ide-taking-forever) and [this one as well](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28631/how-do-i-speed-up-save-deploy-test-in-salesforce-production), but they focus on Eclipse and prod deployments, and therefore introduce a factor of test execution time - my question is in regards to sandbox-to-sandbox quick deploys (no unit tests being executed) using Ant.

Comment: Ha, my first recommendation based on the title was going to be to stop running tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the only thing that I can think of is to have ANT zip (compress) the metadata that you retrieve. It probably won't amount to much of a difference though.

<s>If you're retrieving the metadata from your source org, you'll still be transmitting the uncompressed metadata over the internet. If you're pulling the metadata from a local repository, then you save on that transmission time.</s>

**+edit:** After looking through the docs some more, the `<sf:retrieve>` task is grabbing compressed data. The `unzip` attribute defaults to true, but if you set it to false I'd imagine you could do without the `<zip>` task (unless you're pulling the metadata from a local repo)

**-edit**

a sample ANT target might look like this:

```
<target name="betweenSandboxes">
    <mkdir dir="TempFolder" />
    <sf:retrieve username="<username here>" password="<password here>" serverurl="<url here>" maxPoll="<poll rate here>" retrieveTarget="TempFolder" unpackaged="package.xml"/>
    <zip basedir="TempFolder" destfile="deployment.zip" update="true" />
    <sf:deploy username="<username here>" password="<password here>" serverurl="<url here>" maxPoll="<poll rate here>" zipFile="deployment.zip" testLevel="Default">
</target>
```